# ExpandableListView scroll not proper

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have included a ExpandableListView in xml.When i click on the last item the list automatically opens up by scrolling.
But during scrolling it takes more space approx 3-4dp at the bottom and when i click on the last group it doesn't collapse rather it tries to first adjust itself by coming to normal position(that time the extra space is gone) if i click again to collapse it works fine.

Have any one faced similar issue?This behavior is observed for 1/4 times.

Comment: Which device you tested it on?

Comment: I am trying it on Samsung S5.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your adapter:

```
public void onGroupExpanded(final int groupPosition) {
     super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);

     listView.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
}
```